# Android: SupportActionBar: Home vs Home As Up Icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library

I have two activities that use Android's Support ActionBar; a parent and a child. In the parent, I want to show the home icon. In the child, I want to show the home as up icon. However, the home icon appears to have padding (4 x density), and the up icon does not. Ideally I'd like to align them, so that the UX looks consistent across activities. I have read [Adding the App Bar](http://developer.android.com/training/appbar/index.html), but I'm not sure what the best practices are in this situation. It seems strange that they should be treated different. Should I use the home as up for both activities? Should I add artificial padding to the home icon?

Parent:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

Child:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Have you checked your images to see if they dont have any extra blank space around them?

Comment: I considered that. I am using the same mipmap for both icons, but the mipmap does have a few pixels of blank space all around

Comment: If I use a drawable with no blank space as the icons, the issue still occurs, but thanks for the thought!